# Germ as subset of $\mathbb{C}^n$

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry, sheaf-theory

I am reading "Complex Geometry: an introduction", by D. Huybrechts.

In the definition, 1.1.22 says that a germ $X\subset \mathbb{C}^n$ in $0$ is called analytic if $X$ and $Z(f_1,f_2,\ldots,f_n)$ define the same germ, where $f_i \in \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{C}^n,0}$. What is that mean ?

I understand that $Z(f_1,f_2,\ldots,f_n)\subset \mathbb{C}^n$ since it contains all the points where the functions $f_i$ vanishes. I don't understand how $Z(f_1,f_2,\ldots,f_n)$ is a germ and how a germ $X$ can be thought as a subset of $\mathbb{C}^n$.

The book doesn't define very rigorously what a germ is but from the definition 1.1.14 I assume it means it's the set of all the equivalence classes $(U,f)$.
Where $(U,f)\sim (V,g)$ if there exist $W\subset U\cap V$ such that $f|_W=g|_W.$

Maybe I understand wrong the definition but can someone explain what we mean when we write the germ $X\subset \mathbb{C}^n$ ?

Comment: The $f_j$ are germs of holomorphic functions at $0$, so their common zero set is well-defined on some (small) neighborhood of $0$. That gives a germ of an analytic subvariety.

Comment: @TedShifrin What definition are you using for the germs ?

Comment: I'm fine with what you wrote, but you need to specify that these are specifically neighborhoods of $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I assume it means it's the set of all the equivalence classes $(U,f)$.

That is the germ of a *function* $f$. The germ of a subset $X \subset \mathbb C^n$ at zero is an equivalence class of *subsets*. Two subsets $X, Y \subset \mathbb C^n$ define the same germ at zero, if there exists a neighbourhood $U$ of $0 \in \mathbb C^n$, such that
$$X \cap U = Y \cap U.$$
So $X$ and $Y$ look the same near zero.